# Redirecting standard output to text file

Tags: bash, awk, outputstream, fileoutputstream

I am attempting to execute a program called **fasterq-dump**. This program takes some folder *SRRXXXXXXXX* as input and outputs text files. It also allows one to redirect the data for the files it creates straight to standard output with the flag **-Z**.

I pipe this standard output through **awk** to stream alternating groups of four lines through **pigz** to two separate files, *1.fq.gz* and *2.fq.gz*. Here is the command in its entirety:

```
fasterq-dump  -e 14 -t ./SRR21719548 --split-spot -Z | awk '{if ((NR-1) % 8 < 4) {print | "pigz --fast -p 14 > 1.fq.gz"} else {print | "pigz --fast -p 14 > 2.fq.gz"} }'
```

Aside from the data it sends to standard output (which I caught and sent to **awk**), it also prints a few lines after its completion:

```
spots read      : 26,507,360
reads read      : 53,014,720
reads written   : 53,014,720
```

**I would like to append the above three lines to a text file.** I append the 'redirection' additions to my command like so:

```
fasterq-dump  -e 14 -t ./SRR21719548 --split-spot -Z | awk '{if ((NR-1) % 8 < 4) {print | "pigz --fast -p 14 > 1.fq.gz"} else {print | "pigz --fast -p 14 > 2.fq.gz"} }' [REDIRECT_ADDITION]
```

However, any addition I make to the command shown above results in an empty .txt file being created, and the three lines still printing to standard output.

I have tried the following as additions to the end of my command:

```
> log.txt
&> log.txt
>> log.txt
&>> log.txt
>> log.txt 2>&1
2>&1 | tee -a log.txt
```

As mentioned, all of these result in an empty **log.txt** and the three lines still printing to standard output.

I have read through tens of posts on StackOverflow, none of which seem to address this error. I know for certainty that my permissions are sufficient, and I am executing these in the bash shell.

I assume there is some aspect of bash that I am missing here, but I cannot figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The final lines of stats are likely being printed to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.  (many utilities output statistical info on `stderr` to allow content redirection without the stats) I don't know if that is the case, but check. You can use a braced-group, e.g. `{ ... your commands here ... } > newfile` to redirect all output from however many commands are between `{ ... }` without having to worry about truncate/append redirections.

Comment: Or just redirect stderr for only for `fasterq-dump` by putting a redirect *before* the pipe, something like `fasterq-dump  -e 14 -t ./SRR21719548 --split-spot -Z 2>>log.txt | awk ...` (the "2" means redirect file descriptor #2, which is stderr, and `>>` means "append" instead of "overwrite").

Comment: Using curly braces resulted in bash pausing, expecting further input. However, I tried grouping the command with regular parentheses and it behaved as expected. As well, you were correct about the output being directed to stderr. Much appreciated.

Comment: @gladshire When using curly braces to group commands, you need a semicolon or line break before the close brace; without that it's just treated as another command argument.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Was not aware! Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

As ***David C. Rankin*** pointed out, the output was being directed to stderr rather than stdout. Although several my initial redirections accounted for stderr, surrounding the entire first command with parentheses worked:

```
fasterq-dump  -e 14 -t ./SRR21719548 --split-spot -Z | awk '{if ((NR-1) % 8 < 4) {print | "pigz --fast -p 14 > 1.fq.gz"} else {print | "pigz --fast -p 14 > 2.fq.gz"} }' >>log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Don't write duplicate code - `awk '{n=(((NR-1) % 8 < 4) ? 1 : 2); print | ("pigz --fast -p 14 > "n".fq.gz")}'`

Comment: Also, all of your output is being redirected to a .gz file so `>>log.txt 2>&1` won't capture any stdout and would be clearer capturing stderr with `2>>log.tx` instead.

Comment: Greatly appreciate the advice. I am only now getting more familiar with the structure of more advanced bash commands. Was not aware that there was a shorter way to execute this. Thanks!